# traceroute only shows first hop

Tags: networking, vmware, traceroute

I'm trying to use *traceroute* on a VMware guest Linux machine, and this is the result :

```
traceroute to 172.217.9.228 (172.217.9.228), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.10.0.1  183.499 ms  193.008 ms  192.763 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

Host OS is windows and I tried the equivalent command (tracert) on windows and it shows about 26 hops with their IPs.

Why is this happening? And what configuration should I change to make it work?

**UPDATE**

I found out when no response is returned to *traceroute* it shows an asterisk (*), so the problem must be between the host OS and VMware guest.

Comment: By default *nix: uses UDP scans. windows: uses ICMP scans. If one works better than an other, switch to this one, so apples can be compared to apples (use traceroute -I).